# how to create a Db when im currently connected to another DB in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

*Is it possible to create a any function in mongoDB to create a new DB by staying inside another DB . by using any commands like USE,CONNECT)
If so please provide me the link or suggest any answer*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to explicitly create a database.  You can use it right away.

```
>use newdb
// insert a new document into a collection
>db.things.insert({attr:'someValue'})

>show collections
system.indexes
things

>show dbs
 local  (empty)
 newdb  0.203125GB
```

Comment: Actually . im trying to create another Db by staying inside a another DB. say for ex. im in metadb and im using the below function stored in mongoDb db.system.js.save({_id: "try" , value : function () { db1 = connect("localhost/myDatabase"); db1.new.insert({x: "a"}); } } }); and accessing through node js. using Eval .. but im unable to create a Db . Y so  node js code  var mongoose =  mongoose.connect('localhost','metadb');
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {

mongoose.connection.db.eval("function({try})" , function (err, retval) { 
  });
});